# Looping over a monadic predicate

Tags: haskell, monads, predicate

For looping over a function until a predicate holds there is

```
until :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

Yet, this falls short once the predicate has the form

```
Monad m => (a -> m b)
```

The only way I found out of this is via explicit recursion, e.g. when reading from a handle until `EOF` is reached:

```
  (_, (Just stdout), _, _) <- createProcess (proc "task" (args fl)){ std_out = CreatePipe }
  let readH :: IO [Either String Task] -> IO [Either String Task]
      readH l = do eof <- hIsEOF stdout
                   if eof
                     then l
                     else do line <- hGetLine stdout
                             l' <- l
                             readH.return $ (eitherDecodeStrict' line) : l'
  out <- readH $ return []
```

Is there a higher order function that simplifies this? Maybe together with [sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence)?

Comment: See [Control.Monad.Loops](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.3.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html) which contains a lot of useful monadic functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a "monadic until" function yourself, for example

```
untilM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m a
untilM p f = go
  where
    go x = do r <- p x
              if r
                then return x
                else do a <- f x
                        go a
```

or perhaps, if your predicate doesn't need an argument,

```
untilM :: Monad m => m Bool -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m a
untilM p f = go
  where
    go x = do r <- p
              if r
                then return x
                else do a <- f x
                        go a
```

or even, you don't want any arguments at all,

```
untilM :: Monad m => m Bool -> m a -> m ()
untilM p f = do r <- p
                if r
                  then return ()
                  else do f
                          untilM p f
```

Comment: Thanks! If you mention monad-loops this is a perfect answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let's refactor your code until we arrive at such a combinator.

```
let readH :: IO [Either String Task] -> IO [Either String Task]
    readH l = do eof <- hIsEOF stdout
                 if eof
                   then l
                   else do line <- hGetLine stdout
                           l' <- l
                           readH.return $ (eitherDecodeStrict' line) : l'
out <- readH $ return []
```

First I want to point out the superfluous `return`s. In this code you never call `readH` without an accompanying `return`. The argument to `readH` can actually be pure by simply removing the unnecessary returns. Notice that we had to add `return l` on the `then` branch, and no longer have to "perform" `l' <- l` on the else branch.

```
let readH :: [Either String Task] -> IO [Either String Task]
    readH l = do eof <- hIsEOF stdout
                 if eof
                   then return l
                   else do line <- hGetLine stdout
                           readH $ (eitherDecodeStrict' line) : l
out <- readH []
```

Okay, now I'm going to rename a few things for clarity and slightly reformat.

```
let -- how to check the stop condition
    condition :: IO Bool
    condition = hIsEOF stdout
let -- what IO to do at each iteration
    takeOneStep :: IO ByteString
    takeOneStep = hGetLine stdout
let -- what pure work to do at each iteration
    pureTransform :: ByteString -> Either String Task
    pureTransform = eitherDecodeStrict'

let readH :: [Either String Task] -> IO [Either String Task]
    readH theRest = do
      isDone <- condition
      if isDone
        then return theRest
        else do
          raw <- takeOneStep
          readH (pureTransform raw : theRest)

out <- readH []
```

Make sure you understand how this version of the code is the same as the last version; it just has a few expressions renamed and factored out.

`pureTransform` is a bit of a red herring here. We can bundle it with `takeOneStep` instead.

```
let -- how to check the stop condition
    condition :: IO Bool
    condition = hIsEOF stdout
let -- what IO to do at each iteration
    takeOneStep :: IO (Eiter String Task)
    takeOneStep = do
      line <- hGetLine stdout
      return (eitherDecodeStrict' line)

let readH :: [Either String Task] -> IO [Either String Task]
    readH theRest = do
      isDone <- condition
      if isDone
        then return theRest
        else do
          thisStep <- takeOneStep
          readH (thisStep : theRest)

out <- readH []
```

Re-read the body of `readH` at this point. Notice that none of it is specific to this particular task anymore. It now describes a general sort of looping over `takeOneStep` until `condition` holds. In fact, it had that generic structure the whole time! It's just that the generic structure can be seen now that we've renamed the task-specific bits. By making `takeOneStep` and `condition` arguments of the function, we arrive at the desired combinator.

```
untilIO :: IO Bool -> IO (Either String Task) -> [Either String Task] -> IO [Either String Task]
untilIO condition takeOneStep theRest = do
  isDone <- condition
  if isDone
    then return theRest
    else do
      thisStep <- takeOneStep
      untilIO (thisStep : theRest)
```

Notice that this combinator, as implemented, doesn't have to be constrained to `Either String Task`; it can work for any type `a` instead of `Either String Task`.

```
untilIO :: IO Bool -> IO a -> [a] -> IO [a]
```

Notice that this combinator, as implemented, doesn't have to even be constrained to `IO`. It can work for any Monad `m` instead of `IO`.

```
untilM :: Monad m => m Bool -> m a -> [a] -> m [a]
```

The moral of the story is this: by figuring how to write "looping over a monadic predicate" via explicit recursion for your particular use case, you have already written the general combinator! It's right there in the structure of your code, waiting to be discovered.

There are a couple ways this could be cleaned up further, such as removing the `[]` argument and building up the list in order (currently the list comes out reversed, you'll notice), but those are beyond the point I'm trying to make right now, and so are left as exercises to the reader. Assuming you've done both of those things, you end up with

```
untilM :: m Bool -> m a -> m [a]
```

Which I would use in your example like so:

```
(_, (Just stdout), _, _) <- createProcess (proc "task" (args fl)){ std_out = CreatePipe }
out <- untilM (hIsEof stdout) $ do
  line <- hGetLine stdout
  return (eitherDecodeStrict' line)
```

Looks a lot like an imperative-style "until" loop!

If you swap the argument order, then you end up with something nearly equivalent to `Control.Monad.Loops.untilM`. Note that unlike our solution here, `Control.Monad.Loops.untilM` (annoyingly!) always performs the action before checking the condition, so it's not quite safe for use in this case if you might be dealing with empty files. They apparently expect you to use `untilM` infix, which makes it look like a `do-while`, hence the flipped arguments and "body then condition" nonsense.

```
(do ...
    ...
) `untilM` someCondition
```

Comment: Thanks for the great strategy! Actually `whileM` was what I needed, but I’ll keep those things in mind when I next refactor.